# How to delete certain words from files with shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, cpu-word

I have to delete every word containing at least one number from each file given through the command line as parameter. This is my code:

```
while [ "$*" != "" ]; do
    if [ ! -f $1 ]
        then echo "$1 not file"
    else
        sed -ie  "s/[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*//g" $1
    fi
    shift
done
```

It works perfectly if I have only *one* file, but if I have more it gives the same result for each. After I run the script in each file there will be the result of the first one.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

EDIT2:

This is what I'm running now:

```
while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
for file in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
        printf "file doesn't exist: %s\n" "$file"
        continue;
    fi
    if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
        printf "not a file: %s\n" "$file"
        continue;
    fi
done
    sed -i "s/[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*//g" "$file"
done
```

*I was talking about the done for the while loop and the done for the for loop; but even without that my script keeps running.*

EDIT:

Basically the same thing just a bit different. I have to delete the second and fourth word from each line from each file (word only contain alphanumeric characters). Its' not working properly and I cant find the error. This is my code:

```
while [ "$*" != "" ]; do
    if [ ! -f $1 ]
        then echo "$1 not file"
    else
        sed -ie  's/^\( *[^ ]+\) +[^ ]+\(.*\)/\1\2/
                  s/^\( *[^ ]+\)\( +[^ ]+\) +[^ ]+\(.*\)/\1\2\3/g' $1
    fi
    shift
done
```

Comment: you don't need the `while` loop if you're going to use the `for` loop. Just use what I answered, it replaces all of your first code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the while loop condition should check if there are no arguments, and if there are it should continue. So the right form would be

```
while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
```

Now, what you really want is to *get each argument* and do something with it. That automatically implies a *for loop*. So what you really should be doing is

```
for file in $@; do
```

Now, a file can have spaces in it, so getting that filename and checking if it is really a file should be **quoted**, and you should also check for existance first

```
for file in "$@"; do
    if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
        printf "file doesn't exist: %s\n" "$file"
        continue;
    fi
    if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
        printf "not a file: %s\n" "$file"
        continue;
    fi
    sed -i "s/[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*//g" "$file"
done
```

I could expand more on `sed` where the `-i` switch is restricted only to GNU sed. Apart from that you may also want to keep a backup of that file in case something goes wrong.
But this is another topic I guess.

Comment: the code you posted gave me this error: "sed5jo.sh: 8: Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "then")" , but using while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do seems to have solved my problem. tyvm. any suggestions to the 2nd problem im having? (wrote it in the edit) im not too good with patterns :(

Comment: whoops, you're right, it's `if [..]; then` not `if [..]; do` my fault, fixed now.

Comment: hmm. youve missed `done` before the `sed` command. and if its added the script starts running and it works correctly, but doesnt stop. any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. `done` is there as it should be, `sed` runs for every file. The script should come to end when all files are processed. What's the script you're running ?

Comment: try this to remove the 2nd and 4th word in a line:  
  
`sed 's/^\([[:alnum:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+[[:alnum:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\([[:alnum:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+[[:alnum:]]\+\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3/'`  
  
Definitely not clean, but you can play with it, and get to know character classes.

Comment: All of this error checking is redundant and incorrect.  Just invoke sed: it will emit a perfectly good error message if the file does not exist.  In addition, it will output that error message to the correct stream. (Your version prints the error message to the wrong stream.)